# Find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ of $\lim_{h\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{h} = 5$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Suppose the function, $f$, is differentiable at $x = 1$. $$\lim_{h\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{f(1+h)}{h} = 5$$

Find a) $f(1)$ and, b) $f'(1)$.

I know b) (well at least I think it can) can be found by the definition of the derivative, i.e.

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} $$

Therefore,

$$f'(1) =5-\lim_{h\rightarrow\ 0}\frac{f(1)}{h} $$

However, I'm stuck for a).

Comment: If the denominator tends to $0$ then what must happen to the numerator if the limit exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;f\;$ differentiable at $\;x=1\;$ then it is *continuous* and, of course, defined there. But

$$f(1)\neq 0\implies \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1)}h\;\;\text{doesn't exist}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

if $f$ is differentiable at $1$ then it is continuous at $1$. For $h\neq 0$ we have:

$$f(1+h)=h\times\frac{f(1+h)}{h}$$

What equality will arise if $h\to0$?

Comment: perfect hint. +1